# BEM: List items and styling?

Tags: css, bem

I am new to BEM and working on a sample template:

**HTML**

```
 <header class="header">
  <div class="header__branding">
    <h1>Site branding</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="header__menu">
    <nav class="main-menu">
      <ul class="main-menu list">
        <li class="list__item"><a href="" class="list__item-link">link</a></li>
        <li class="list__item"><a href="" class="list__item-link--active">link</a></li>
        <li class="list__item"><a href="" class="list__item-link">link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>

<footer class="footer">
  <div class="footer__links">
    <ul class="???? list">
      <li class="list__item"><a href="" class="list__item-link">link</a></li>
      <li class="list__item"><a href="" class="list__item-link">link</a></li>
      <li class="list__item"><a href="" class="list__item-link">link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</footer>
```

**CSS**

```
.main-menu .list{
  // styles here
}

.list__item{
  // styles here
}

.list__item-link{
  // styles here
}

.list__item-link--active{
  // styles here
}
```

So my questions is, what is the best way to name lists and how best to organize the CSS? I got stuck in the footer, I added a ???? if someone can help me think of a better name for the footer links?

I am finding it hard to wrap my head around BEM, but I should not nest more than one element at a time right?

Answer (score 2):

Think about BEM as reusable component that can be placed many times on site in different places.

In this case you don't need any more class in  only 'list'. Both in header and footer.

If you need any modification you could use somethig like: 'list list--wider' or so. And this second class change only width of element.

And one more: list__item-link is wrong. Parent is 'list__item' so this should be named 'list__item__link' BUT you also could name it just 'anchor' or 'link' and you will be able reuse them all around site on `<a>` elements.

Comment: Thank you Ula! Yes, I see what you mean, I guess being new to BEM I just want to go crazy trying to class everything. So just to confirm, it would just be styled with CSS like: .main-menu .list and .footer .list? I use Scss but don't like to nest.

Comment: Yes, BEM is very annoying on first glance! I've been there :) but makes more sense in time when css gets more and more lines of code.

Comment: Yes tell me about it! :) I just get more confused with how people show how to nest but I will give more generic classes for reusable components then. Do I need to also give classes to all of my elements like h1 and span classes even if they don´t have any css? Thanks again Ula.